# Are theorems in a mathematical theory effectively checkable?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

I wonder whether it is possible to effectively check whether some theorem of a mathematical theory (for example group theory) is provable from axioms of that theory. I know that in propositional logic and for example Hilbert's axiomatic system, it is possible to effectively check whether a theorem follows from it's premises/axioms. I also know that in 20th century there were efforts in mathematics to formalize mathematics (maybe so that it would be possible to effectively check whether a theorem follows from axioms of the theory?). Let's say I want to check by a computer whether a theorem follows from axioms of the group theory. Is it possible to check it by a computer? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: Keep in mind that all provers run some sort of SAT solving and are as a result in the NP realm, that means not really efficient

Comment: It depends on what you mean by effective. There are algorithms which halt if the theorem is provable or refutable (and tell you what its status is) but don't halt if the theorem isn't provable from the axioms - but those algorithms aren't efficient at all - and they can't tell you if something is undecidable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends crucially on what objects you are trying to study. First, we fix a theory, say that of Abelian Groups, Graphs, ZFC, etc. Then we can ask if there is a program meeting the following specification:

> Given a sentence $\varphi$ in the theory of interest, output either
>
> - a proof of $\varphi$ from the axioms, which tells us that every model satisfies $\varphi$
> - a model $\mathfrak{M}$ which satisfies $\lnot \varphi$, showing that there is no proof of $\varphi$.

This problem is called the **Decision Problem** for $T$, since it decides if a formula is provable or not. We say that a program which does the above **decides** $T$. If such a program exists, then we say $T$ is **decidable**, and if no such program exists, then $T$ is **undecidable**.

As I said, trying to determine if a theory is decidable or not is a fairly delicate field of study. One thing you should know before starting is that *efficient* algorithms are fairly hard to come by. A lot of decision procedures, when they exist, are [doubly exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function) in runtime.

---

For convenience, here is a quick selection of some results in this area:

- The theory of Groups is undecidable
- The theory of Abelian Groups is decidable
- The theory of $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ is decidable

  - More generally, any theory admitting [Quantifier Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination) is decidable
- The theory of $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ is decidable
- The theory of $(\mathbb{N}, \times)$ is decidable
- The theory of $(\mathbb{N}, +, \times)$ is undecidable

  - More generally, any theory powerful enough to "do logic" inside of it is undecidable. This is basically the [first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)
- The theory of Graphs is undecidable
- The theory of Graphs *is* decidable if we restrict attention to $\forall^*\exists^*$ formulas

---

Some useful references might be [this wikipdedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Some_decidable_theories), as well as

- Rabin's "Decidable theories"
- Tarski, Mostowski, and Robinson's "Undecidable theories"
- Ferrante and Rackoff's "The computational complexity of logical theories"

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: There is no need to involve models in your specification.

Comment: @beroal Would you be so kind to elaborate?

Comment: @lisyarus The decision problem for $T$ is a program that outputs "true" if $\phi$ follows from $T$ and "false" if it does not. The program is not required to output a model.

Comment: @beroal I see, thank you. Still, I like the constructive spirit of the definition used in this answer.